# Derivative Question: How to do the following

Tags: derivatives

How should I take the derivative of the following:

$$\frac{t^2}{(1+t^4)^{1/2}}$$

I know the answer and I have tried quotient rule and product rule and I can't seem to succeed.

Comment: Are you sure your answer isn't equivalent to the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. So what strategy would you use?

Comment: Did you remember to do the chain rule when differentiating $(1+t^4)^{1/2}$?

Comment: Quotient or product will give the correct answer. But based on the functions involved, the answer you want may have been simplified in a way that looks different from what you get from just using the rules.

Comment: For the product rule I get f(t)=t^2  f'(t)=2t   g(t)=(1+t^4)^(-1/2)     g'(t)= (-1/2)(1+t^4)^(3/2)*4x^3        Then t^2*(-1/2)(1+t^4)^(3/2)*4x^3+(1+t^4)^(-1/2)*2t       Is this so far correct?

Comment: Exponent should be -3/2 and you have an $x$ instead of $t$ but the rest looks fine.

Comment: You were right then I am unable to simplify this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with the Quotient Rule you could reorganize the expression
$$
\frac{t^2}{(1+t^4)^{1/2}}
= t^2\cdot\left(1+t^4\right)^{-1/2}
= \left(t^{-4}\right)^{-1/2}\cdot\left(1+t^4\right)^{-1/2}
= \left(t^{-4}+1\right)^{-1/2}
$$
and use the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Quotient Rule, we get

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{t^2}{(1+t^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)
&= \dfrac{(1+t^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 2t-t^2\cdot\frac{1}{2}(1+t^4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot4t^3}{1+t^4} \\
&= \dfrac{2t(1+t^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}-2t^5(1+t^4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{1+t^4} \\
&= \dfrac{2t(1+t^4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left((1+t^4)-t^4\right)}{1+t^4} \\
&= \dfrac{2t}{(1+t^4)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align}
$